# How to update column value in case of array of struct in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Animal: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- Elephant: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- Lion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Zebra: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Dog: string (nullable = true)
```

I just want to is this posible to update the array of struct to some value if I Have a list of column of which I dont want to update.
For eg
If I have a list List[String] = List(Zebra,Dog)
Is this possible to set all other array of column to 0 like Elephant and Lion will be 0

```
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks            |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[1, 1, 0, 1]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[0, 1, 1, 0]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
After operations It will be
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks            |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[0, 0, 0, 1]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[0, 0, 1, 0]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
```

I was going by iteration by row
Like I made a function

```
def changeValue(row :Row) = {
//some code
}
```

But not able to do so

Comment: is below solution is not working ??

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> ddf.show(false)
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks            |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[1, 11, 111, 1111]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[2, 22, 222, 2222]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+


scala> val columnsTobeUpdatedInWebhooks = Seq("zebra","dog") // Columns to be updated in webhooks.
columnsTobeUpdatedInWebhooks: Seq[String] = List(zebra, dog)
```

**Constructing Expression**

```
val expr = flatten(
    array(
        ddf
        .select(explode($"webhooks").as("webhooks"))
        .select("webhooks.*")
        .columns
        .map(c => if(columnsTobeUpdatedInWebhooks.contains(c)) col(s"webhooks.${c}").as(c) else array(lit(0)).as(c)):_*
    )
)

expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = flatten(array(array(0) AS `elephant`, array(0) AS `lion`, webhooks.zebra AS `zebra`, webhooks.dog AS `dog`))
```

**Applying Expression**

```
scala> ddf.withColumn("webhooks",struct(expr)).show(false)
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks      |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[0, 0, 0, 1]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[0, 0, 1, 0]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
```

**Final Schema**

```
scala> ddf.withColumn("webhooks",allwebhookColumns).printSchema
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- elephant: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- lion: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- zebra: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- dog: integer (nullable = false)
```